# Can we define One FOREIGN KEY as more than Two columns in one Table?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

This is my Database Table which is giving Error..

Foreign key Define in more then Two columns ..

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EC_ATTENDEES` (
  `S_ID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `USER_ID` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  `TYPE` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
`TIMETABLE_ID` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  `COURSE_FEE` INT NULL ,
  `PERMISSION` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  `PAYMENT_STATUS` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  `BEGIN_CLASS_NUM` INT NULL ,
  `END_CLASS_NUM` INT NULL ,

    FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID` ) REFERENCES `EC_USER` (`S_ID` ),
    FOREIGN KEY (`BEGIN_CLASS_NUM` ) REFERENCES `EC_TIMETABLE` (`S_ID` ),
    FOREIGN KEY (`END_CLASS_NUM` ) REFERENCES `EC_TIMETABLE` (`S_ID` ),
    FOREIGN KEY (`TIMETABLE_ID` ) REFERENCES `EC_TIMETABLE` (`S_ID` ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the type of one of the foreign key columns doesn't match the type of the referenced column. Two of your columns mentioned in the foreign keys (`BEGIN_CLASS_NUM` and `END_CLASS_NUM`) have type `INT`, and the other one (`TIMETABLE_ID`) has type `VARCHAR(30)`. The referenced column (`S_ID`) can only possibly be one of the two, so either one or two of the foreign keys will generate errors.

Answer (score 0):

It could not possible, your linking is incorrect.